# What's the meaning of highlighted questions?

Tags: support

Sometimes the Top Questions page shows certain questions highlighted, like the accelerometer question in the screenshot below.

[image]

What does the highlighting mean?

**edit**
From Oli's comment it appears that the highlighting isn't clear on every screen. To clarify: the second of the three questions is on a bit darker background than the other two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kevin's on the right track](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/812/whats-the-meaning-of-highlighted-questions/815#815) - just not completely there. The highlighting is indeed the one that is used for favorite tags. However, you probably don't have any favorite tags.

What happened is called "frequented tags". If a user has *zero* favorite and ignored tags, then the system will just quietly watch your habits and infer a pseudo-favorite based on what tags you've been frequently visiting. They will be temporarily highlighted in the same fashion as favorite tags.

The method of disabling it is to have some manner of favorite or ignored tag. It doesn't have to be a real tag, though. If you want to, there's also [a Meta request to allow opting out of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/please-let-users-opt-out-of-the-frequented-tag-system) that you may support.

Answer (score 3):

[Your favorited tags](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2064/stevenvh?tab=prefs) are highlighted.  Your ignored tags are grayed out, or removed entirely if you select "hide ignored tags".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All highlighted questions seem to have the `arduino` tag, but that's not in my favorites, and neither did I filter them. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at a few and comparing, I think it just means the answer has already been accepted.

Edit - I thought it *might* be to do with questions containing someones first answer/question, but now I see it's probably not. Interesting one this, I can't see any pattern.

Edit again - Think I *might* have figured it out, it seems it might be to signify you have not looked at it yet, or it has had activity since you last did. If I go back to before I joined, all answers are  highlighted, but if I click on one then go back it is no longer highlighted.

Comment: No, if it was that easy I already would have found out. BTW, questions with an accepted answer are indicated by the number of answers in a green box, like the first one in the examples.

Comment: I thought you meant the green box. I see you are actually talking about the pink highlighting, which is almost invisible on my screen.

Comment: Also, I think the pink background is replaced by blue highlighted letters on my browser (Chrome)

Comment: @Oli - The blue highlighted letters indicate that you have viewed or not viewed a question.  They use the `CSS:visited` pseudo-class, so they're local to your current browser.

Comment: @Kevin - Ah I see, thanks - that's what I though above but still not even close to the right answer to Stevens question :-) I think I have never seen the pink highlighting shown as I haven't made any tags favorite yet (hence assuming it was the blue instead for my browser) Something to try out...